# What does this line of assembly do ? how am i to interpret it?

Tags: assembly

ive started studying reverse engineering, and in a binary i am trying to reverse i stumbled upon an unusual(to me) line of assembly in IDA PRO. and it looks like this

```
.text:00000000008A1C21                 mov     r8d, ds:(off_8A40FC - 400000h)[rcx+rax*4]
```

so i know that it moves something into the r8 register which is the size of a dword, but i do not understand what it moves into it ? something from the data segment, but im clueless as of how to interpret it, any help would be great.

Comment: in general, it is good to provide additional information about the context an instruction is found in, not just the instruction itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the assembly is doing is subtracting `0x400000` from the offset `0x8A40FC` giving `0x4A40FC`, then using the new address at memory address `[rcx+rax*4]`. I recommend studying the assembly more, this is a bad question as its not giving full detail on what `rcx`, and `rax` is.

Happy hacking! :-)

Comment: Yeah im still pretty new to this and understand basic assembly, this particular instruction was early on in a function i am reversing so i don't know what rcx and rax is.

Comment: so another way of writing this could be [rcx + rax * 4 + 0x4A40FC] ?

Comment: No, that index is at that specific point. With the code you provided you would be at that index, not `[rcx+rax*4]` . And no problem!! I'm happy to see you learning :-)

Comment: Also, I suggest marking this answer as the accepted answer as it solved your problem (hopefully)